# bind_rows and tidyeval splicing fails

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

Subsetting and then binding works as expected

```
var <- c("wt", "mpg")
mtcars %>% select(!!!var) -> df1
mtcars %>% select(!!!var) -> df2
bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

But if we skip intermediate steps

```
bind_rows(
   mtcars %>% select(!!!var),
   mtcars %>% select(!!!var)
)
```

it fails with `Error: only lists can be spliced`

Comment: This is a bug in rlang, can you post an issue there please.

Comment: Actually I just opened an issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang/issues/217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in rlang that has to do with *value splicing*. All functions taking dots support splicing, even if they are not quoting their input. This is handy because you don't have to use `do.call()` with these functions when you have a list of arguments, you can just splice the list.

The mechanism is a bit different for technical reasons. There's currently a bug and value-splicing instead of call-splicing is used within the `select()` call. This should be fixed shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I never use `!!` or `!!!` because there is often something that goes wrong.
Instead, I use `UQ`. I don't know if it's good practice, but it works.

```
bind_rows(
  UQ(mtcars %>% select(var)),
  UQ(mtcars %>% select(var))
)
```

Comment: @lionel This is possible. But why does it give the same result?

Comment: It gives the same result because it doesn't do anything. In Rickard's version the splicing creates this call: `select("wt", "mpg")`. In your version `UQ()` doesn't do anything and the select call ends up looking like this: `select(c("wt", "mpg"))`, which works as well (but won't work in next version, see https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2904)